# Easy way to replace ImageFont.getsize(text) to ImageFont.textbbox(text) in Pillow 10+

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Before Pillow 10, you could use the method getsize(), but after 10+, this method was deprecated.
You can easily change it to getbbox() adding two more lines.

```
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import requests
from io import BytesIO


def text_on_image(image, text, font_size, color):
    req = requests.get('https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/raw/main/src/hinted/Roboto-Regular.ttf')
    img = Image.open(image)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(BytesIO(req.content), font_size)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    image_width, image_height = img.size
    # old way using getsize()
    # text_width, text_height = font.getsize(text)
    # using pillow 10+
    left, top, right, bottom = font.getbbox(text)
    text_width = right - left
    text_height = bottom - top

    draw.text(
        ((image_width - text_width) / 2, (image_height - text_height) / 2),
        text,
        fill=color,
        font=font
    )

    img.save('last_image.jpg')
```

I hope you may be helped with this code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This appears to be an answer not a question???

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
def getsize(font, text):
    left, top, right, bottom = font.getbbox(text)
    return right - left, bottom - top
```

you can replace  `font.getsize(text)` by `getsize(font, text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, using `text_height = bottom - top` looks fine, but is misleading.

The old code `text_width, text_height = font.getsize(text)` needs a different replacement `text_height = bottom` to give identical results.